# Stress the independence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

When I do probability theory, problems like this always get me stuck:

For a sequence of random variable $\{X_n\}$, if $X_n\to 0$ a.e., then $S_n/n\to 0$ a.e. where $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$.

For the condition $X_n\to 0$ a.e., it means that except for a null-measure set $N$, $X_n(\omega)\to 0$ for $\omega\in \Omega\backslash N$. Now for the same $\omega$, $S_n(\omega)/n\to0$ is naturally true by simple calculus, so $S_n/n\to 0$ a.e..

But sometimes I feel maybe the problem is asking the case where $S_n$ is like a "trajectory", by which I mean each $X_n$ maybe have different $\omega$, and our measure space is actually increasing. For $S_n$, it takes value from $\Omega^{\times n}$, and the corresponding probability measure becomes $\mathbb{P}^{\times n}$. If we think it in this way, the method above fails.

I feel that the two different ways of understanding $S_n$ could make the problem totally different. I wonder whether the difference lies in the assumption of independence of $\{X_n\}$? If we change the problem into

For a sequence of independent random variable $\{X_n\}$, if $X_n\to 0$ a.e., then $S_n/n\to 0$ a.e. where $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$.

Then we must consider the latter case?

Comment: Independence has nothing to do with this result. That is only an issue if the variance of $S_n$ comes into play, which is not the case here as the proof you mention clearly shows. "each $X_n$ maybe have different $\omega$" Not sure I understand what you mean here. Note that $S_n(\omega) = X_1(\omega) + \ldots + X_n(\omega)$ so for this to make sense all $X_n$ has to be defined on the same sample space.

Comment: Sometimes I see problems like “suppose random variables $X_n$ independent (and satisfy some condition) prove that $S_n/n$ converges a.e. to $c$. For example, toss a quarter and denote the head and tail by -1 and 1, then $X_n$ in this case are i.i.d, and we know $S_n/n$ converges to 0, but we have to deal with it in the sense of a trajectory, where every $X_n$ may have different values. (If we take the same $\omega$ for all $X_n$, then all $X_n$ have the same value since they are identically distributed!)  I got entangled here.